# Counting unique values in subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, posts and votes, where votes has post_id. I want to count how many posts have 1 vote, 2 votes, 3 votes and so on.

When I'm using this query

```
select count(post_id) from votes group by post_id
```

I'm getting following results

```
3
3
1
2
2
2
1
```

Now I want to count how many times I got 3, 2, 1:
So I want to get

```
3 2
2 3
1 2
```

But when I'm trying to count results from the subquery, I'm getting following error:

```
select x,count(x) from (select count(post_id) from votes group by post_id) as x group by x;
ERROR:  column "x.count" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select x,count(x) from (select count(post_id) from votes...
```

And I can't group by count too, because when I'm doing it, I'm getting following:

```
  x   | count                                                                                                                                                                                
------+-------                                                                                                                                                                               
 (1)  |     1                                                                                                                                                                                
 (2)  |     2                                                                                                                                                                                
 (3)  |     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to group by `x` which means you are trying to group the whole subselect and not the `count` value. That's the problem.

If you are grouping only by your `count` value you get your expected result:

```
SELECT 
    x.count_per_post_id,
    count(x.count_per_post_id)
FROM (
    SELECT
        count(post_id) as count_per_post_id
    FROM
        votes
    GROUP BY post_id
) x
GROUP BY x.count_per_post_id
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e3181ca580a68b984df46602dfe3762a)

Comment: No it works without an alias as well. But I wouldn recommend it. The problem was that in your query you were not addressing the column (which is names after the function - count) but the whole subquery (x). If you use x.count instead of x it works.